# Loading symbol while Json parsed

Tags: javascript, blazor

How I can I go about adding loading symbol in index.js while Json is being parsed.

razor page:

```
<div id="container"></div>   @*Where data is going to be displayed*@

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("Create", data);    @*invokes JS method*@

}
```

index.js:

```
function create(data){

     // loading show start here
     $.getJSON(FN, function (data1) {
            ....
     });
     //Should end here

 }
```

Comment: your loading triggers should be inside of the ``$.getJSON`` callback

Comment: Why are you doing this in JS? Use what Blazor offers and add it to the Blazor Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the loading spinner markup (`HTML`) and start it off hidden.

When `create` function is invoked, display the spinner and finally when `getJSON` callback is invoked, hide the spinner.

(Don't mind the dummy js, it is just there for this example snippet to work, and you should focus on the `loading` element in the `create` function)

```js
// Javascript


// Dummy
const $ = {
  getJSON(fn, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback(fn + " to put on screen"), 3000);
  }
}
const fn = "Something";
create();
// Dummy

function create(data) {

  // loading show start here
  loading.classList.remove("hidden");

  $.getJSON(fn, function(data1) {
    //Should end here
    loading.classList.add("hidden");

    // Set text inside the container div
    container.textContent = data1;

    // ....
  });

}
```

```css
/* CSS */

.loading {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading svg {
  width: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  fill: lightsteelblue;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="loading" class="loading hidden">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12,4V2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12H4A8,8 0 0,1 12,4Z"></path></svg> Just running for 3 seconds
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you. Is there a chance that we can start loading this symbol from  method in razor page? And end loading symbol after parsing in JS.

Comment: Sorry don't know razor, but you could remove the `hidden` class from the loading `div`. This will display the loading spinner as soon as it gets rendered, but if that is not what you want, then I'm sorry that I can't help further. Maybe post a new question on SO?